# Map the .local domain and subdomain for docker container in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, 22.04, docker, nginx, container

I have a Linux server with Ubuntu 2022, whose IP is 192.168.100.82, and to access applications running on Docker, I need to enter the IP address and port, there are three applications on ports 3000, 5001, and 8080 respectively (Gitea , Documize and Jira) My server is located on an internal data center and the information is as follows:

```
$sudo hostname -I
192.168.100.82 172.18.0.1 172.17.0.1 150.50.50.1
```

> the 150.50.50.1 is a my docker network.

```
$hostname
nitro-web
```

.....

```
$ cat /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 nitro-web
### The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

###### so, i Didn't install NGINX in my VPS yet becuz i dont understand the nginx config for docker container apps.

in finally i want to map this domain for containers:

```
192.168.100.82:8080 ----> jira.nitro.local
192.168.100.82:3000 ----> git.nitro.local
192.168.100.82:5001 ----> doc.nitro.local
```

Regards.